# Make table use page width

Tags: tables

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\title{F}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\secion{foo}
\subsection{Interface (queries, stored procedures)}

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    create\_queue(OUT rv SMALLINT) \\
    delete\_queue(\_queue\_id BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    insert\_message(queue\_id BIGINT, source\_client\_id BIGINT, target\_client\_id BIGINT, rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    read\_top\_message(\_queue\_id BIGINT, client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    delete\_top\_message(\_queue\_id BIGINT, client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    queue\_exists(\_queue\_id BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    get\_queues(OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    epoche\_ms(OUT rv BIGINT) \\
    get\_queues\_with\_pending\_messages(client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    read\_message\_by\_sender(\_queue\_id BIGINT, \_client\_id BIGINT, \_source\_client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status BIGINT) \\
    delete\_message\_by\_sender(\_queue\_id BIGINT, \_client\_id BIGINT, \_source\_client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    create\_client(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    client\_exists(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    get\_clients(OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    create\_client(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output (essentially):[image]
How can I make the table use the empty space on its left side?

N.B. I searched for solutions and found quite a number of solutions - many involving tabular* - but I could not make them work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your options

First, use `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}` instead of `l` column.

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}


\title{F}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{foo}
\subsection{Interface (queries, stored procedures)}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
    \hline
    create\_queue(OUT rv SMALLINT) \\
    delete\_queue(\_queue\_id BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    insert\_message(queue\_id BIGINT, source\_client\_id BIGINT, target\_client\_id BIGINT, rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    read\_top\_message(\_queue\_id BIGINT, client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    delete\_top\_message(\_queue\_id BIGINT, client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    queue\_exists(\_queue\_id BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    get\_queues(OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    epoche\_ms(OUT rv BIGINT) \\
    get\_queues\_with\_pending\_messages(client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    read\_message\_by\_sender(\_queue\_id BIGINT, \_client\_id BIGINT, \_source\_client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status BIGINT) \\
    delete\_message\_by\_sender(\_queue\_id BIGINT, \_client\_id BIGINT, \_source\_client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    create\_client(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    client\_exists(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    get\_clients(OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    create\_client(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Second, use `tabularx`

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\title{F}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{foo}
\subsection{Interface (queries, stored procedures)}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
    \hline
    create\_queue(OUT rv SMALLINT) \\
    delete\_queue(\_queue\_id BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    insert\_message(queue\_id BIGINT, source\_client\_id BIGINT, target\_client\_id BIGINT, rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    read\_top\_message(\_queue\_id BIGINT, client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    delete\_top\_message(\_queue\_id BIGINT, client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    queue\_exists(\_queue\_id BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    get\_queues(OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    epoche\_ms(OUT rv BIGINT) \\
    get\_queues\_with\_pending\_messages(client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    read\_message\_by\_sender(\_queue\_id BIGINT, \_client\_id BIGINT, \_source\_client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status BIGINT) \\
    delete\_message\_by\_sender(\_queue\_id BIGINT, \_client\_id BIGINT, \_source\_client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    create\_client(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    client\_exists(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    get\_clients(OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    create\_client(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Third, if you want to stick with `l` column type, use this:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}


\title{F}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{foo}
\subsection{Interface (queries, stored procedures)}
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    create\_queue(OUT rv SMALLINT) \\
    delete\_queue(\_queue\_id BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    insert\_message(queue\_id BIGINT, source\_client\_id BIGINT, target\_client\_id BIGINT, rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    read\_top\_message(\_queue\_id BIGINT, client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    delete\_top\_message(\_queue\_id BIGINT, client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    queue\_exists(\_queue\_id BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    get\_queues(OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    epoche\_ms(OUT rv BIGINT) \\
    get\_queues\_with\_pending\_messages(client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    read\_message\_by\_sender(\_queue\_id BIGINT, \_client\_id BIGINT, \_source\_client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status BIGINT) \\
    delete\_message\_by\_sender(\_queue\_id BIGINT, \_client\_id BIGINT, \_source\_client\_id BIGINT, OUT rv TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    create\_client(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    client\_exists(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    get\_clients(OUT rv BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF BIGINT \\
    create\_client(\_clientId BIGINT, OUT status SMALLINT) \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I have used a box of `\textwidth` and centered it. Since the table is too wide, I have also reduced the text size to `\footnotesize` (which people don't like generally).

Comment: Marvelous answer. Your help is much appreciated.